# Show the available payment methods based on the value stored in DB

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form for the user select the payment method (credit card or references). But the payment methods should appear on the form based on what is stored in the DB. The conferences table has a column "payment_r" and "payment_c". If payment_r" or payment_c" are "1" they should appear on the form if they are 0 should not appear. Or if one is 1 and the other is 0 the payment method that is 1 should appear.

Do you know how to properly achieve that?

Like below is not working, any payment method appear but it should appear one because the `payment_c` is "1". The     `{{dd($conferenceDetails)}}` shows:

```
array:3 [▼
  "name" => "Conference test"
  "payment_r" => 1
  "payment_c" => 0
]
```

Form:

```
<form method="post" id="step1form" action="">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    {{dd($conferenceDetails)}}
    <h6>Select the payment method</h6>

    @if(isset($conferenceDetails->payment_r) == 1)

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="payment_method"
                   value="references">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                <span class="mr-auto">References</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        @endif
       @if(isset($conferenceDetails->payment_c) == 1)
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="payment_method" value="credit_card">
            <label class="form-check-label d-flex align-items-center"
                   for="exampleRadios1">
                <span class="mr-auto">Credit Card</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        @endif
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to modify your @if statement from `isset` to `!empty` which would check if isset and also if not 0 as well.

Here's how it would look:

```
@if(!empty($conferenceDetails['payment_r']))

@if(!empty($conferenceDetails['payment_c']))
```

Comment: Thanks, but still dont appear like that!

Comment: The {{dd($conferenceDetails->mb)}} shows  "Trying to get property of non-object (".

Comment: Can you show your controller that you send to view? I didn't notice the "MB" in your code sample above.

Comment: Sorry its "The {{dd($conferenceDetails->r)}}".

Comment: Your db data above shows fields of name, payment_r, and payment_c, is there an additional "r" field somewhere? You can try removing your {{dd($conferenceDetails)}} line from view I assume that was just to test and it should show the output. You can set the data from 0 to 1 and 1 to 0 to see the different outcome.

Comment: Like this it seems that works "{{dd($conferenceDetails['payment_r'])}}
".